# APA style references in Devanagari script

Tags: biblatex, biber, indic

I am using package `biblatex` for references in Devanagari script. My TeX engine is XeLaTeX.

This is my minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Sanskrit 2003}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. \underline{\cite{अर्जुनवाडकर}} हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे. हा एक परिच्छेद आहे.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`references.bib` has this entry.

```
@book{अर्जुनवाडकर,
  title={मराठी व्याकरण : वाद आणि प्रवाद},
  author={अर्जुनवाडकर, कृष्ण},
  year={१९८७},
  publisher={पुणे : सुलेखा प्रकाशन}
}
```

My output looks like this -

[image: 1]

The problem here is in my preamble I've specified the style as `apa`. This style uses initials of the author names. In Latin script if I write 'Krishna', apa style will take 'K.' as the author name. As I am writing in Devanagari, my input is 'कृष्ण'. Devanagari is a syllabic script and hence it's conventions differ from the Latin ones. A character represents the vowel sound in it. We tend to write 'कृ' (क + ृ) as the initial and not 'क' (which is there in my screenshot). `biber` is eating up the diacritics. How to redefine the commands of biber for Devanagari initials?

Comment: Does this happen with any other style like `authoryear`?

Comment: `authoryear` style takes the full name (unlike APA as it takes the initial). So no, this issue won't come anywhere else APA (and styles which take initials. I don't know all of them.)

Comment: What if you set `giveninits=true` option and use `authoryear`?

Comment: Yes! Then it is again eating up the diacritics.

Comment: 'कृ' itself has two unicode characters. U+0915 for क and U+0943 for   ृ

Comment: Alright then I will check - it likely is nothing to do with the APA style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fear that this is pushing even the ancient and hacked `btparse` library to its limits. It can deal with most Unicode for initials generation but not combining diacritics. However, `biber` has its own extended name format for just this situation, simply change your `.bib` to:

```
@BOOK{अर्जुनवाडकर,
  AUTHOR    = {family=अर्जुनवाडकर, given=कृष्ण},
  TITLE     = {मराठी व्याकरण : वाद आणि प्रवाद},
  YEAR      = {१९८७},
  PUBLISHER = {पुणे : सुलेखा प्रकाशन}
}
```

`biber` itself does understand extended grapheme clusters and so will correctly generate initials in such cases. It will auto-detect the extended name format and not use `btparse` to parse the name. This gives:

[image]

You can also explicitly give the initials you want in this extended format but it's not necessary in your case.

**UPDATE:** Biber 2.14+, supports this in the usual name format too so your example will work without using the extended name format. Biber, from version 2.14, no longer uses an external library to generate initials and so is able to deal with all Unicode initials situations correctly by default.

I also wanted to mention two other things:

1. `biber` can sort sanskrit correctly as it has support for transliteration specifically for sanskrit, see `\DeclareSortTranslit` in the `biblatex` manual
2. Your `YEAR` field generates a `biber` warning because it's not detected as an integer. I am looking into this in general (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/284)

**UPDATE:** `biber` 2.14+ allows arbitrary Unicode numerics in the `YEAR` and `MONTH` fields and they will even sort correctly with no warnings. Unicode numerics for `*DATE` and all integer fields are supported too and so compatibility for scripts is complete.

Comment: This is exciting. I didn't know that Biber would generate initials differently when the extended name format was used.

Comment: Oh yes, `biber` uses real EGCs to do this. `btparse` does its hacked best (which is fine for most cases) but it will never be able to do this for every scenario - it would need a complete rewrite.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the normal name format benefit from this as well? I'm thinking only get the full name parts from `btparse` and generate the initials as in the extended name format.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me.

Comment: @moewe - yes I have managed to do this and form 2.14, initials generation will be done by `biber` directly and so examples like this will not need the extended name format to work correctly.