# Interpretation of Devanagari characters in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode, xstring

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec,xstring}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Shobhika}

\begin{document}
    \StrChar{abcd}{1} % Returns a
    \StrChar{क्ष}{1} % Returns क, but should return क्ष (क+्+ष)
\end{document}
```

The character I have written is a "complex character" composed of three characters, but they together constitute a single one. This particular case is of conjunction. `्` is particularly used for conjoining two characters. There is also another pattern which gives us full syllables. Consonant characters are combined with vowel diacritics to form a syllable. For example /kā/ will be written with the consonant `क` (k) & vowel diacritic diacritic `ा` (ā), but together `का` will constitute a single character. This is because Devanagari is known to be a [syllabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabary) (or a alpha-syllabic) script. In syllabic scripts, every character represents a syllable.

This was a theoretical description of the working of Devanagari script. Thus Devanagari script needs a different counting pattern in my opinion. What counts as a "character" does not depend upon the number of symbols. There are different combinations which constitute a single character. Is there any other such alpha-syllabic script known to TeX. This has popped up again and again for various reasons. I had the same problem with `biblatex`. You can look into it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507093/174620) as a question or the same problem as a (solved) GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/920). I don't know how they managed to solve it, but that particular problem with biber is fixed. As this problem is coming again and again in different places, I think it would be better to have a different character level interpretation for Devanagari script which is not based on the scripts with alphabetic nature.

Any ideas?

Comment: well this problem is not restricted to devanagari. This happens in almost every script. For example if I input á as a + combining accent, StrChr will return only the a, and a ligature like ffi is split too. In some scripts the order of some glyphs are reversed in output. But this is not something a string processor can and should handle, it operates on the input.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Your example makes sense, but I still don't really get your point regarding the string processor. As the definition of character differs in alphabetic and syllabic scripts, there will be differences in the required string operations. eg. If I want my program to return the first "character" of my string, then it should be giving me the character with the diacritic. (even in the case of your example.) What is the advantage of calling `á` two characters when in fact one of them is an inferior character?

Comment: Shouldn't there at least be a way to expect the right output when asked for one? (Any kind of redefinition probably)

Comment: There is no advantage. But to *decide* that `á` or your devanagari  is one character or that the ij is one char in dutch but two in german or which is the first char when you input `ক` and `ি` in bangla (which gives `কি`), you need large lists of language/script dependant informations.  A perl script like biber which has access to all the unicode files describing this can do it (in parts), but not a simple string processor.

Comment: Can we do it with the help of `polyglossia`? (As it is internal to TeX and it already has a large database of languages.) See what I want is a TeX internal way to process the strings with language-specific needs.

Comment: So for example `xstring` will process input characters differently when the default language is set to Marathi, differently when it is English and so on...

Comment: I understand what you want. But you seem not to understand that string processing and text processing are two quite different beasts. If you are a tug member you should get the newest tugboat and read Joseph's article about case changing.

Comment: No unfortunately I am not :( Can you recommend a text processing tool which is internal to TeX?

Comment: No, I doubt that it can be done based only on the input. It depends e.g. on the font if ffi is a ligature or not. You probably need to pass the input to a font shaper and then inspect the returned nodes - you could do it with luatex. But at first you should perhaps research what unicode has to say about character counting.

Comment: @Niranjan anything that you write in tex (like xstring) can only have information about character tokens. The text shaping that you describe happens in xelatex below the level of tex as harfbuzz prepares a sequence of glyphs taken from the font.  xetex has no access to this information at all via its tex interfaces. As Ulrike says if you use luatex then (in principle) you can access the nodes returned from the text shaping using Lua.

Comment: Okay thanks :) I shall read more on the working of XeTeX.

Comment: @Niranjan you do have access to the individual elements of a combining character of course, so you could write your own macro to split a string into a list of 'proper' characters from the byte representations, and use this list to extract the nth proper character. Such a macro can be written fully in LaTeX, and might work for simple cases as you describe in your question. But no doubt you will run into difficulties to properly implement all details of Devanagari.

Comment: @Marijn can you demonstrate how to achieve what you have said for my MWE? I would like to experiment more with the code and check where exactly the problem arises.

Comment: @Niranjan today I don't have much time, but I think the question is interesting so I would like to give it a try and write an answer at some point.

Comment: @Marijn the shaping rules of devanagari aren't easy. There is a reason why lualatex didn't correctly support the script for a long time, and why we needed harfbuzz. I don't know the rules but I have e.g. some doubts that it is enough to look forward at the next character.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not suggesting to reimplement HarfBuzz in TeX, however it may be helpful for the OP and others to implement some rules in TeX to cover a few common cases for use in `\StrChar` type of macros, and to manually correct more complex cases. Or maybe it's not useful. But as a proof of concept you don't need to go to the level of the font shaper and back I think.

Comment: @Marijn I have seen this type of questions before: they start with a simple rule (replace every x with u) and this looks easy to implement and then the rules are expanded one by one until it gets unmanagable. Better ask first about the whole set that is expected here and don't rely on one example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are misinterpreting my question. When Marjin said that it is possible to write such a macro, I was curious to see an example-code with which I can experiment more. I have said that in my comment too. You should not generalize your experiences.

Comment: Marcel Krüger just wrote, that he is about to upload a package name lua-uni-algos, which contains a module "to identify a grapheme cluster, a unit of text which is perceived as a single character by typical users, according to the rules in UAX \#29, section 3.". It could help you, but it will require luatex.